# npm unmet peer dependency on the package being installed

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm a bit baffled as to why I get an unmet peer dependency on the exact package I'm trying to install.

I run:

```
npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.27 --save-dev
```

Result:

```
angular2-webpack-starter@5.1.1 C:\src\angular2-webpack\angular2-webpack-starter

-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.1.0-beta.27
```

I'm running the latest version of node and npm.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Full output:

```
-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.1.0-beta.27
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9.11 but none was installed.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: Is that the entire output? I would have expected that there'd be a few more lines about which package needed that dependency.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I've pasted the full output

Comment: I think your bigger issue is that `extract-text-webpack-plugin` is for Webpack 1 only (it has a range of `^1.9.11` which means `>=1.9.11` **and** `<2.0.0`). Try fixing that first, then see if you still have the issue.

Comment: Consider switching `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to `v2.0.0-beta.4` (which does support Webpack 2)

Comment: @Aurora0001 Thanks for the great help, now I get `bootstrap-loader@1.3.1` requires a peer of `extract-text-webpack-plugin@<2.0.0` but none was installed.

Comment: Try `v2.0.0-beta.16` for `bootstrap-loader` as well then.

Comment: @Aurora0001 You're a legend, I'd be more than happy to accept this if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error isn't actually coming from Webpack, but instead (as we determined in the comments) it came from outdated versions of `extract-text-webpack-plugin` and `bootstrap-loader`. Since you're using Webpack 2, you'll need to use the v2 beta versions of your plugins.

To fix this, upgrade:

- `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to `v2.0.0-beta.4`
- `bootstrap-loader` to `v2.0.0-beta.16`.

It's a bit strange that npm highlighted Webpack as the missing peer dependency, but npm does tend to have quite unclear error messages that take a  while to get used to.